# Elastic IP billing charges

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-ip

Referring to this document https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-ip-charges/

> An Elastic IP address doesn’t incur charges as long as the following conditions are true:
>
> The Elastic IP address is associated with an EC2 instance.
>
> The instance associated with the Elastic IP address is running.
>
> The instance has only one Elastic IP address attached to it.
>
> The address is from a BYOIP address pool.
>
> You're charged by the hour for each Elastic IP address that doesn't meet these conditions. For pricing information, see Elastic IP Addresses on the Amazon EC2 pricing page.

Will I be charged if the address is BYOIP but not associated with any running instance?

Answer (score 0):

The page you quoted is ambiguously written.

The original announcement is more clear:

> There is no additional charge to use the BYOIP feature.
>
> Also, you don’t have to pay for Elastic IP addresses that you create from BYOIP address prefixes.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/announcing-the-general-availability-of-bring-your-own-ip-for-amazon-virtual-private-cloud/